# Compute $P(\mu-2\sigma<X<\mu+2\sigma)$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete crandom variable whose probability mass function is given by $f_X(t)=(1/2^t)$ for $t=1,2,3,\cdots$ and zero otherwise.

Then, I am supposed to  compute $P(\mu-2\sigma<X<\mu+2\sigma)$.

I computed mean $\mu$ to be $2$ and variance $\sigma^2$ to be $6$.

Then $P(\mu-2\sigma<X<\mu+2\sigma)= P(2-2\sqrt{6}<X<2+2\sqrt{6})=f_X(1)+f_X(2)+\cdots+f_X(6)$.

But this is greatest than $1/4$ which contradicts the Chebyshev's inequality. I am confused as what went wrong. I am sure there is some silly computational error,. but, I could not find where did I miscalculated.

Any comments are useful.

Comment: Are you sure, that you got the variance right? I believe it should be $\sigma^2=2$.

Comment: Also Chebyshev's inequality states $P(|X-\mu| \geq 2\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{4}$, which means that $P(|X-\mu| < 2\sigma) > \frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: That is correct, I miscalculated variance and misremember the inequality... Thanks boss :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your $X$ follows a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with $p = \frac{1}{2}$, so $\sigma^2 = \frac{1 - p}{p^2} = 2$.

Also, [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) asserts that:
$$
\mathrm{P}(|X - \mu| \color{red}{\geq} k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}
$$
This means that, in your case you should be checking the following:
$$
\mathrm{P}(\mu - 2\sigma < X < \mu + 2\sigma) > 1 - \frac{1}{2^2} = \frac{3}{4}
$$
Which is indeed true.

Comment: That is correct, I miscalculated variance and misremember the inequality... Thanks boss.